# how to introduce a condition in a react-props?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, if-statement, react-props

i am very new to react and do not know how to introduce the following condition into a property.
I'm using a component of ui material and I want to introduce the condition that if "error= true" it should be set to "disabled=false"

```
return (
  <MuiTextField
    value={value}
    disabled={disabled}
    error={error}
    fullWidth={fullWidth}
    label={<span className={classesLabel.inner}>{label}</span>}
    helperText={helperText}
    onChange={handleChange}
    classes={{
      root: classes.root,
    }}
    
    
    {...props}
  />
);
}
```

what I would like to do is to introduce at the point of the error attribute a condition similar to this

```
error={error,{if (error) { disabled = false}}}
```

I know the syntax is not correct but it is a way of explaining what I want to do

Someone to give me an idea of how to introduce this condition?
Many

Comment: something like `disabled={disabled && !error}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
const MUITextDisabledProps = { disabled: false};

return (
    <MuiTextField
        value={value}
        disabled={disabled}
        error={error}
        {error && ...MUITextDisabledProps}
          ... other props
    />
);
```